# Is jumping limited to half basic move when exhausted?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills

If I'm reading the rules for the jump skill correctly, it is not possible to do a jump longer that one's base move. Since an exhausted character may move only half base movement, this implies that his maximum jump is half his basic move when exhausted. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first assumption is incorrect. That is why the whole answer is: **No**

Let us start with general [Jump rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/jump.htm), that state (in Action paragraph):

> If you run out of movement mid-jump, your next action (either on this turn or, if necessary, on your next turn) must be a move action to complete the jump

So, no, it is possible to do a jump longer than one's base move. It is possible to jump even longer than your double move, if it is of interest to you.

Let us now go to your main question of how does [exhausted](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#exhausted) condition affect jumping:

- It reduces your Strength score, so your Jump check will be lower than usual;
- It (as you pointed out) reduces your speed by half. That part reduces your Jump check even further;
- It, as an extension of [fatigued](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#fatigued) condition, states, that you can not run or charge. Jump checks usually require "running start" for their DC's to not be doubled. But, despite calling it "running", rules do not require you to actually use Run action to achieve it. Hustling, which normal combat movement is, is enough for that. If it matters, running start may be taken during another move action <sup>**1**</sup> (or even in the previous round). It just have to be taken right before the jump itself.

What this condition doesn't do, it doesn't set any upper limit on your Jump check. So, your jump distance will be limited by the final result of your Jump check only.

---

1) credits go to Hey I Can Chan.

Comment: Although implied, it'd probably be good to mention that to get a running start the rules don't mandate that the 20 ft. in a straight line be during the *same* move action.

Comment: I don't need the shout-out, but thank you. I was actually thinking that, for example, an exhausted dwarf could take a move action to move 10 ft. then take a second move action to  move 10 ft. then make a Jump skill check, the dwarf's next move action (and, perhaps, beyond?!) being automatically occupied by the movement from the Jump skill check. (And, I think, according to the rules, one could spend 4 turns *crawling* in a straight line then make a Jump skill check with a "running start"... which is just silly. Thank heavens this isn't a RAW question.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I still think one should move his speed, not crawl. Even moving half speed is walking, and shouldn't be sufficient for **running** start. It' just my seeing though, as I don't know of any RAW definition of it (don't personally think someone needs it very much).

Comment: So, because rules say: "Distance moved by jumping is counted against your normal maximum movement in a round." A jump have a duration of rounds equal to the total lenght of the jump divided by basic movement?

Comment: @Fanaval A duration of Move Actions equal to the total length of the jump divided by basic movement. You may take two of them in the round.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

Jump

> Distance moved by jumping is counted against your normal maximum movement in a round.

So when you can only move half movement rate during exhausted - you can only jump half movement rate while exhausted.

Note: You can't jump more than what you can normally move. So if your movement is 15' because you are exhausted, you can jump 15'. But you can't get a running start. You can't walk 15' and then jump 15'.